# Grouping_ID syntax error in oracle with functions

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Can some one point me to the error in the following syntax.

This is working fine.

```
SELECT col1,col2,grouping_id(col1)col3,substr(col2,1,5)col4
FROM tab1
GROUP BY col1, col2,col3,col4
HAVING GROUPING_ID(col1)<=5 order by 1,2,3,4;
```

This is not:

```
SELECT col1,col2,grouping_id(col1)col3,substr(col2,1,5)col4
FROM tab1
GROUP BY col1, col2,col3,col4
HAVING GROUPING_ID(col1,substr(col2,1,2))<=5 order by 1,2,3,4;
```

How to use functions in the grouping_id in oracle?

Error msg:ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substr(col2,1,2)` is not a group by expression, but `substr(col2,1,5)` is.
You should add to `SELECT` projection `substr(col2,1,2)` or replace `substr(col2,1,2)` by `substr(col2,1,5)` in `GROUP BY`

Comment: Or maybe use substr(substr(col2,1,5), 2) :)